# How to invoke method of Apex Class using API in .net

Tags: rest-api, api

I have one Button in Visualforce Page. On click of button one method of apex class is called.

I want to call that apex class method from my C# application using API.
Is this possible to call apex method from c# application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your existing apex class method into webservice and then generate a wsdl out of it and you can consume that in your .net application.

your current visualforce button can still access the same apex class method as well.

here's some references on [creating apex webservices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) and a [consuming them in .net](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications) applications

Comment: Krishna, Thanks for giving answer. Is this the final approach? Is there any other (may be complex) approach to achieve this?

Comment: @rakesh This is the approach that I am familiar with. However you don't need to convert the existing apex class. You can build a wrapper around it.

The wrapper doesn't have to be a SOAP service. You could also build a wrapper that exposes the class as REST service. You'll need to create a connected app for this.